# pass a variable to handle dot notation in a object

Tags: javascript

Here is an explanation of what I want. let's say we have an array of objects.

the first `console.log` works as expected but I can't make the second one work correctly... I want the second `console.log` to do the same thing as the first one.

How can do this?

```js
     var sentences = [
    { passed: {mean: 10, shadow: 11, write: 12}}
];
        
        let a = 'mean';
        console.log(sentences[0].passed.mean)
        console.log(sentences[0].passed.a);
```

Comment: `sentences[0].passed[a]`

Comment: Thank you guys plus one ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log(sentences[0].passed[a])`

This uses `a` as a variable.

Comment: last question why this doesn't work? `console.log(sentences[0].passed[a]++)` but this one works: `console.log(sentences[0].passed[a]+1)`

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the output of those two statements?

Comment: please have a look at my questions Edit

Comment: got it!............

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for this:

```js
var sentences = [{
  passed: {
    mean: 10,
    shadow: 11,
    write: 12
  }
}];

let a = 'mean';
console.log(sentences[0].passed.mean)
//Like this:
console.log(sentences[0]['passed'][a]);
//or this:
console.log(sentences[0].passed[a]);
```

Since `a` is a variable, you need use bracket notation to get the value from the object's corresponding property (dot-notation won't work in that way)